# Cat returns "command not found" when parsing my text instead of returning a string's output

Tags: bash, shell, cat

Here are my commands:

```
mail_recipient_location="$PWD/mail_config/myFile.txt" 
textVariable= [ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ] && `cat "$mail_recipient_location"`
```

My terminal shows that `cat` returns:

```
{the mail's adress's value in myFile.text}: command not found
```

How can I lead `cat` to just inject the file text's value in the textVariable?

Comment: I apologize, I have modified my code to make it more readable :).

Comment: No apology needed in this case, later edits are to be avoided, but the sooner you do an edit, the better in general.

Answer (score 4):

Error is on this line:

> ```
> textVariable= [ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ] && `cat "$mail_recipient_location"`
> ```

the backticks evaluate the output of `cat "$mail_recipient_location"`, which is the mail address. That's clearly not what you want. Remove the backticks. If you only remove the backticks, still the code will not work because there is a blank space after the equal sign, which means textVariable will always be set to the empty string.

Additionaly, backticks are not recommended. The following looks like cleaner code and does what you want:

```
if [ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ]; then
    textVariable=$(cat "$mail_recipient_location")
fi
```

Comment: and if this is bash, you can write: `textVariable="$(< "$mail_recipient_location")"` -- ref [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: and pedantically, the backticks don't "evaluate the output" -- the backticks *produce* the output, and it's the shell's parsing of what follows `&&` that does the evaluation (i.e. a command is expected there).

Comment: @glennjackman At least Q has pointed out actually POSIX-ly correct code. It's a nice bonus to the nice explanation he had provided. I advise not to recommend Bashisms if not needed for the case.

Answer (score 4):

If you debug your script using `set -x` or `bash -x`, it will print:

```bsh
+ mail_recipient_location=/somepath/mail_config/myFile.txt
+ textVariable=
+ '[' -f /somepath/mail_config/myFile.txt ']'
++ cat /somepath/mail_config/myFile.txt
+ the mail's adress's value
```

After it evaluates

```
[ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ]
```

it expands your `cat "$mail_recipient_location"` and ignores `textVariable=`, as already mentioned by Quasimodo. So, it tries to execute `the mail's adress's value` which is not a command, obviously.

To achieve what you want, you can use this: (Also, you should avoid [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)):

```bsh
# oneliner
[ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ] && textVar=$(<"$mail_recipient_location")

# or
if [ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ]; then
   textVar=$(<"$mail_recipient_location")
else
   : # do something
fi
```

Non-POSIX, works on `bash` and `zsh`

Comment: @roaima True, I merely wanted him/her to know about it, and maybe mention it, which indeed he/she did. Deleting comment.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Yes, I wasn't aware about that before, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're not far off. Try this

```
mail_recipient_location="$PWD/mail_config/myFile.txt"
[[ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ]] && textVariable=$(cat "$mail_recipient_location")
```

First check the file exists. Then assign the variable.

For POSIX environments the `[[ ... ]]` needs to be replaced with `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
[ -f "$mail_recipient_location" ] && textVariable=`cat "$mail_recipient_location"`
```